# Проверка на совпадение переменной со значением из списка

Tags: python, переменные

Помогите составить короткое условие:

•есть переменная (список) `admin` и в ней много значений чисельных

•если выпадет хоть одно значение которое есть в переменной `admin`,условие должно выполниться

•желательно составить через`if`

Comment: 1) ответ несложный (и соотвествует рекомендации языка - в таких случаях надо `in` использовать), можете принимать, но что вы с ним делать будете теперь, если не секрет? 2) На будущее обратите внимание на то, как я исправил ваш заголовок. Он должен давать ясное понимание о смысле вопроса - выше вероятность получить помощь, и выше вероятность, что другие найдут его в базе знаний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Выпавшее" - в переменной znachenie.

```
if znachenie in admin:
    print ("Выполнилось!")
```